# Amadeus cheapest dates REST endpoint not working

Tags: endpoint, amadeus

I'm trying to reach the endpoint of the cheapest dates and I'am always getting the following error.

```
        "status": 500,
        "title": "SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED",
        "detail": "No price result found for requested destination"
```

It's not possible to find anything. I've tried for example, MAD to BCN (A typical flight). The same issue occurs from JFK to LAX... and so on.

I'm trying to reach the endpoint calling it and adding my Bearer accessToken and everything is fine (no errors) but I don't get any result.

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=MAD&destination=BCN&duration=8&maxPrice=900&currency=EUR

I've even tried using the example provided on the Amadeus website and having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are currently working on the dataset we have in the test environment for this API.
Very soon you will have the exact list published on our portal with a better selection of origins and destinations.

You can find [here](https://amadeus.box.com/s/kbp6ml6jm78w3mi6qd8qvaxoijopqcs0) (remember it's a temporary list that will be deleted in the future) the list of origin:destination and dates available for the Flight Inspiration Search & the Flight Cheapest Date Search API.

I will update this answer when the new list is available on the portal.

Comment: This still seems to be a problem - even if I use the list published here - https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightsearch.md - is this still broken?